# Why videojs progress bar is not staying fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

i have problem with `videojs` progress bar . it is not staying fixed.

**Question:** how to make progress bar fixed when it is in `hover` or `normal` state.

**Observe below 2 screens:**

when we move cursor on video its progress bar is moving up. i want it to be fixed.

**normal:**

[image]

**Hovered:**

[image]

**Note:** i want to use same `videojs version`

here is what i have tried:

```css
   .vjs-fluid {
      overflow: hidden;
   }
   
   #example_video_1 .vjs-control-bar {
      display: block;
   }
   #example_video_1 .vjs-progress-control {
         bottom: 28px;
         left: 0 ;
         height: 10px;
         width: 100%;
   }
   
   .video-js .vjs-progress-control:hover .vjs-play-progress:after {
         display:none;
   }
```

```html
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs.markers.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.js"></script>


<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480" controls data-setup='{ "inactivityTimeout": 0 }'>
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood your query in my previous answer and I apologize for that.

**Updated Answer:**

Remove the `height` attribute and add `font-size: 10px` in your CSS like this

```
#example_video_1 .vjs-progress-control {
     bottom: 28px;
     left: 0 ;
     font-size: 10px;
     width: 100%;
}
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: did not work for me, i think `mouseover` is controlled by `javascript`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem while working on video.js, following css helped me solve the problem.
make sure you priortise the CSS

```
.video-js .vjs-control-bar {
opacity :1!important;
visibility: visible;
}
```

let me know if this solves the purpose.